# Why do I have associated changesets from all branches when I build from a specific branch?

Tags: tfs

We're new to branching and our solution has recently been converted into branches. We have three of them: DEV -> QA -> RELEASE.

We have set up our Release build definition which builds $/OurCollection/TeamProject/Release. After build, in the associated changesets there were changesets that are checked in DEV and changesets merged from DEV into QA. None of this changeset were merged into Release branch. That they show in the associated changesets is quite a surprise. Is this an intended feature which I'm not aware of or did we set up our build wrongly?

I would appreciate any insight into this matter. This is important info since we plan to use associated changesets to build release notes and now there are thing that are not in a build.

Comment: What does your workspace configuration of the build look like? TFS uses the highest common workspace path to find the included folders.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Could you share your build definition?

Comment: @jessehouwing You nailed it. Workspace configuration solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you just mapped the branch `Release` in Workspace mappings. Check the screenshot below:

[image]

If you mapped all branches or the whole team project, then changesets in other branches will be associated.

Comment: Yes! That was it. Thank you so much.